# In WPF how do I Resize main windows during the runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, window, scale

I want my main WPF window during the runtime, when there is not enough space for my control, to resize itself. I could create a window which takes a maximum amount of space on the screen and make it transparent, but are there any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I want my main WPF window during the runtime of my application when there is not enough space for my control"

What does this mean?

You should have a look at SizeToContent property on Window.

Comment: sorry, just was in a hurry hasn't double checked, what I wrote. Thanks for the suggestion.